# Extract principal components

Tags: python, reinventing-the-wheel, numpy

First, I am aware that this can be done in sklearn - I'm intentionally trying to do it myself.

I am trying to extract the eigenvectors from `np.linalg.eig` to form principal components. I am able to do it but I think there's a more elegant way. The part that is making it tricky is that, according to the documentation, the eigenvalues resulting from `np.linalg.eig` are not necessarily ordered.

To find the first principal component (and second and so on) I am sorting the eigenvalues, then finding their original indexes, then using that to extract the right eigenvectors. I am intentionally reinventing the wheel a bit up to the point where I find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, but not afterward. If there's any easier way to get from `e_vals, e_vecs = np.linalg.eig(cov_mat)` to the principal components I'm interested.

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
x = 10 * np.random.rand(100)
y = 0.75 * x + 2 * np.random.randn(100)

centered_x = x - np.mean(x)
centered_y = y - np.mean(y)

X = np.array(list(zip(centered_x, centered_y))).T

def covariance_matrix(X):
    # I am aware of np.cov - intentionally reinventing
    n = X.shape[1]
    return (X @ X.T) / (n-1)

cov_mat = covariance_matrix(X)

e_vals, e_vecs = np.linalg.eig(cov_mat)

# The part below seems inelegant - looking for improvement
sorted_vals = sorted(e_vals, reverse=True)

index = [sorted_vals.index(v) for v in e_vals]

i = np.argsort(index)

sorted_vecs = e_vecs[:,i]

pc1 = sorted_vecs[:, 0]
pc2 = sorted_vecs[:, 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice trick to get the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the covariance matrix *without* ever forming the matrix itself. This can be done using the [singular value  decomposition (SVD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition), as described in [this post from Stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134282/relationship-between-svd-and-pca-how-to-use-svd-to-perform-pca/134283#134283). Not only is this more numerically stable, but the results are automatically sorted.

A python version might look like this:

```
def components(X):
    _, vals, vecs = np.linalg.svd(X - X.mean(axis=0), full_matrices=False)
    return vals**2/(len(X)-1), vecs
```

A few things to note:

- As described in the linked post above, the [data matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_matrix) is typically defined with dimensions as columns, i.e. the transpose of your `X`.
- The principle values and components are typically sorted from largest to smallest, i.e. the reverse of yours.
- The function above does not assume that `X` has been pre-centered.

So to get results comparable to yours, you would need to do:

```
vals, vecs = components(X.T)
e_vals, e_vecs = vals[::-1], vecs[::-1]
```